# Azure MobileService returns NullPointerException (Android)

Tags: java, android, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am testing an android program which links to my Azure with MobileService on Android.

I am able to insert into the table successfully but am unable to retrieve. It returns me a NullPointerException on the callback. I am using the following code:

```
//Global Variable
private MobileServiceClient mClient;
private MobileServiceTable<Table1> mTable; 

// OnCreate 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    try {
        mClient = new MobileServiceClient("https://cstudy.azure-mobile.net/","fmfLCGAIDJVIXoePtriQWzSnSTXqfx57",this);
        mTable = mClient.getTable("Table1",Table1.class);

    } catch (Exception e1) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e1+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }}



//Method that execute onClick      
    mTable.execute(new TableQueryCallback<Table1>() {
        public void onCompleted(List<Table1> result, int count,
            Exception exception, ServiceFilterResponse response) {
            if (exception == null) {
                for (Table1 item : result) {
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+item.getID(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+exception+"///"+response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Any help is gladly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out the problem. 
Your table when using MobileService should be created from the Azure main portal, not the Azure Management SQL portal. 
When creating your table from your Azure main portal, it will create a new schema which will be linked to the Mobile Service.